# python Dataframe using pandas data insert into excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have received a data frame using pandas, data have one column and multiple rows in that column
and each row has multiple data like ({buy_quantity:0, symbol:nse123490,....})

[image]

I want to insert it into an excel sheet using pandas data frame with python xlwings lib. with some selected data please help me

```
 wb = xw.Book('Easy_Algo.xlsx')
 ts = wb.sheets['profile']
 pdata=sas.get_profile()
df = pd.DataFrame(pdata)
ts.range('A1').value = df[['symbol','product','avg price','buy avg']]
```

output like this :

[image]

please help me... how to insert data into excel only selected.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the dataframe below is named `df` and the type of the column `positions` is `dict`, you can use the code below to transform the keys to columns and values to rows.

[image]

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('positions').values.tolist()))

out.to_excel('Easy_Algo.xlsx', sheet_name=['profile'], index=False) #to store the result in an Excel file/spreadsheet.
```

**Note** : *Make sure to add these two lines below if the type of the column* `positions` *is not* `dict`.

```
import ast

df['positions']=df['positions'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

##### #A sample dataframe for test :

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

string_dict = {'{"Symbol": "NIFTY2292218150CE NFO", "Produc": "NRML", "Avg. Price": 18.15, "Buy Avg": 0}',
'{"Symbol": "NIFTY22SEP18500CE NFO", "Produc": "NRML", "Avg. Price": 20.15, "Buy Avg": 20.15}',
'{"Symbol": "NIFTY22SEP16500PE NFO", "Produc": "NRML", "Avg. Price": 16.35, "Buy Avg": 16.35}'}

df = pd.DataFrame(string_dict, columns=['positions'])

df['positions']=df['positions'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('positions').values.tolist()))
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

```
                  Symbol Produc  Avg. Price  Buy Avg
0  NIFTY22SEP16500PE NFO   NRML       16.35    16.35
1  NIFTY22SEP18500CE NFO   NRML       20.15    20.15
2  NIFTY2292218150CE NFO   NRML       18.15     0.00
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have a question having a data frame `https://www.klgrth.io/paste/kvd7j` check this is complete data that I am getting, data have 4 column 4th column name data in data column have another column name `positions` in positions column have multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want only those columns written to an excel file

```
df = df[['symbol','product','avg price','buy avg']]

df.to_excel("final.xlsx") 
df.to_excel("final.xlsx", index = False) # in case there was a default index generated by pandas and you wanna get rid of it.
```

i hope this helps.